# Applying Checkstyles on jsp files?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am using the eclipse checkstyle plugin available at http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/. Checkstyle
works fine on java file but not on jsp file. It does not display any warning on jsp file.

Looks like somehow jsp files are by default excluded but i don't see the  any configuration where i can
include the jsp files so that checkstyle can be applied on them?

Comment: As i said i am already using eclipse-cs but somehow it does not work on jsp file which it is supposed to ?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Checkstyle is not available on JSP and that's normal.
And, avoid to use Scriptlets in your JSP. In addition to all the benefits, it will avoid you this problem.

Some tools or plugins exist to manage JSP code quality. Take a look at [Checkstyle equivalent for JSPs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283078/checkstyle-equivalent-for-jsps) which provide a solution with IntelliJ.

Comment: The link "Checkstyle equivalent for JSPs?" talks about IntelliJ but i am using eclipse. Is there any thing for eclipse?

Comment: On this thread, someone speaks about http://www.myeclipseide.com/htmlpages-func-display-pid-11.html . Don't know what it worths.